# slippry.js plugin is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am learning Web Design using many plugins. slippry.js is one of them but I could not figure what is wrong with my codes given bellow. I get nothing on page. Thank you

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/slippry.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/slippry.css"/>

<script>
JQuery(document).ready(function() {
   JQuery('#pictures-demo').slippry({
   slippryWrapper: '<<div class="sy-box pictures-slider"/>',
   adaptiveHeight: false,
   captions: false, 
   pager: false,
   // controls
   controls: false,
   autoHover: false,

   // transitions
      transition: 'kenburns', // fade, horizontal, kenburns, false
      kenZoom: 140,
      speed: 2000 // time the transition takes (ms)
    }); });
</script>
```

HTML Code (index.html)

```
<div class="sy-box pictures-slider">
<div class="sy-slides-wrap">
    <div class="sy-slides-crop">
        <ul id="pictures-demo">
            <li title="And this is some very long caption for slide 3. Yes, really long.">
                <img src="images/MainBackground.png" alt="demo1_3">
            </li>
            <li title="And this is some very long caption for slide 4.">
                <img src="images/MainBackground2.png" alt="demo1_4">
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some typos like "JQuery" (it must be: "jQuery") or a double < for the property slippryWrapper.

The updated code:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  jQuery('#pictures-demo').slippry({
    slippryWrapper: '<div class="sy-box pictures-slider"/>',
    adaptiveHeight: false,
    captions: false,
    pager: false,
    // controls
    controls: false,
    autoHover: false,

    // transitions
    transition: 'kenburns', // fade, horizontal, kenburns, false
    kenZoom: 140,
    speed: 2000 // time the transition takes (ms)
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/booncon/slippry/master/dist/slippry.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/booncon/slippry/master/dist/slippry.css"/>

<div class="sy-box pictures-slider">
  <div class="sy-slides-crop">
    <ul id="pictures-demo">
      <li title="And this is some very long caption for slide 3. Yes, really long.">
        <img src="http://slippry.com/assets/img/image-3.jpg" alt="demo1_3">
      </li>
      <li title="And this is some very long caption for slide 4.">
        <img src="http://slippry.com/assets/img/image-4.jpg" alt="demo1_4">
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for response. Those typos already fixed, but still shows up nothing.

Comment: @ManTamang On my pc, running windows 10, with chrome, ff and ie when I "Run code snippet" it works! I do not know what I can say to you.

Comment: Ok, I have OSX 10.11.6 running. You reckon it is due to OS ?

Comment: @ManTamang Sorry, my friend, but I hate mac, iphone and ipad. So I'm not the right guy to ask for. I'm sorry but I'm so like I am. Sorry again, and I help you will receive help from other on mac os.  Thanks so much in any case.

Comment: Thank you for you effort dude, appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You mistake is parameter of

> slippryWrapper

hastwo

> starting angular bracket

here :

```
<script>
JQuery(document).ready(function() {
   JQuery('#pictures-demo').slippry({
   slippryWrapper: '<div class="sy-box pictures-slider"/>',
   adaptiveHeight: false,
   captions: false, 
   pager: false,
   // controls
   controls: false,
   autoHover: false,

   // transitions
      transition: 'kenburns', // fade, horizontal, kenburns, false
      kenZoom: 140,
      speed: 2000 // time the transition takes (ms)
    }); });
</script>
```

Comment: Ok, then check in Mozilla FirFox by right clicking your webpage and select Inspect element> Console, you getting any error there related to scrips you have added so far. Also u can use debugger; or alert(); statement to verify if the script is called or not.

Comment: On Console, I have discovered following errors.                                                                                                                                                                                                                              "GET 
http://localhost/SlippryExample/images/MainBackground.png [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 0ms]". Trying to figure out whether script is called or not.

Comment: Script is being called, tested using alert statement.

Comment: ok add MainBackground.png to your SlippryExample/images folder first.

Comment: Images are already in that folder, from the time I started woking on it. "SlippryExample/images" 2 png file.

Comment: I also tried using 2 .jpg pics, throwing same and one more error.                     "TypeError: jQuery(...).slippry(...) is not a function
index.html:17:5"

Comment: I guess there is some mistake here too <script src="js/slippry.min.js"></script> src path should start "~/parent node". Where is js folder in your solution explorer.The src path of img tag is wrong. Also as mentioned by @gaetanoM  j is small in jQuery.

Comment: <img border="1" height="75" src="~/Content/Images/Products/imag2.png" width="100" />. Check the syntax of img tag online

Comment: j is small, previously fixed and slippry.min.js file is coped and pasted in js folder, did nothing with it, replaced with new one again. Inside the SlippryExample->  index.html, "js" folder has (slippry.min.js), "css" folder has (slippry.css).

Comment: @ManTamang I m not saying that slippry.min.js is wrong. The path is wrong. Try to drag and drop that .js file in ur html page. Then send me that script tag.Same is the case for img tag

Comment: <script src="/js/slippry.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/slippry.css" />    
        <img src="~/Content/Images/logo.jpg" />. Notice src attribute. See the syntax of path inside src attribute

Comment: As you said put that .js file in html page folder, No improvement. Relating to path, I think it is ok because I have used typed.js using same path and directory structure, working great. In addition, With the plain HTML, Images are displaying. Problems only occur when using slippry

Comment: Ok.. sorry could not help till end. All the best. And let be the js file wherever it was before. Only u hv change the path in "src" attribute

Comment: <script src="/js/slippry.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/slippry.css" />   was tested before posting here.

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend for your great effort. I will update here If I could fix it.

Comment: I got it working by removing "sy-slides-crop" div. Some reason, when I put it on stops working.